# C++ More Elegant Way to set Default Values in multi-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initialization, default

In my .h file, I have:

```
struct tup{
    tup() : 
    token{{-1,"a","b","c","d","e","f"},
          {-1,"a","b","c","d","e","f"},
          ...
          {-1,"a","b","c","d","e","f"}} {}
    struct {
        int pos;
        std::string nj, ny, pa, ri, ct, fl;
    } token[100];
```

Where the "..." refers to 97 more lines of the same type of code. Is there a more elegant way to set default values for my token?

Comment: Make a default constructor for that inner struct? Also where is this "multi-dimensional" array mentioned in the title?

Comment: @NunsBeachSurfer Why are there only 97 initializers instead of 100?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `97 more lines` they are already showing 3.

Comment: @NathanOliver When what is the problem simply to copy and paste these lines?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You're kidding, right? Have you heard of DRYing?

Comment: @milleniumbug  What is it?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I sorry but maybe I am misunderstanding you.  You said they only have 97 initializer.  I was pointing out thatthey 3 3 in there code and the `...` is for 97 more lines that thy are not posting here giving them 100 intializers

Comment: @NathanOliver And why are not they posted here?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I would assume for brevity and that they are all the same.  They are asking if there is a way to not have to write the 100 lines of code.

Comment: @NathanOliver  But he already did not write the all 100 lines. So it is not clear what is the problem.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Probably for the same reason you don't output every value of the array in your answer to prove the point.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I actually think they did and want to know a better way.  I can't fault them for not posting 100 lines of the same code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are open to using `std::vector` instead of an array, you an use:

```
struct tup{
    tup() : tokens(100, {-1,"a","b","c","d","e","f"}) {}
    struct token {
        int pos;
        std::string nj, ny, pa, ri, ct, fl;
    };
    std::vector<token> tokens;
};
```

Comment: @NunsBeachSurfer, you are welcome. I am glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the constructor could be defined provided that your compiler supports C++ 2014. Otherwise you have to change type `std::remove_extent_t` to its equivalent in C++ 2011.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

struct tup{
    tup() 
    { 
        std::fill( std::begin( token ), std::end( token ),  
                   std::remove_extent_t<decltype( token )>( {-1,"a","b","c","d","e","f"} ) );
    }

    struct {
        int pos;
        std::string nj, ny, pa, ri, ct, fl;
    } token[100];
};

int main()
{
    tup tup;

    std::cout << tup.token[0].pos << ' ' << tup.token[0].nj << std::endl;
    std::cout << "//..." << std::endl;
    std::cout << tup.token[99].pos << ' ' << tup.token[99].nj << std::endl;

}
```

The program outputs is

```
-1 a
//...
-1 a
```

That is in any case you can use standard algorithm `std::fill` as I showed or some other way for example using a lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a constructor in the cpp file (and classes instead of structs). The actual content of the array is an implementation detail that shouldn't be in the header.
The best way is to use a loop (100 items is a tiny number for a computer, you won't see the difference) in an method that initializes the class. It also allows you to handle errors better (constructors cannot return error codes easily; you could use a reference or a member for that, but it's ugly). This is the best approach I can think of.

In your parser, are all the strings just characters? you could simply use a char or char[n+1] if n is the largest size for yours strings. With std::strings, you have static allocation for small sizes (wasting a bit of space) and dynamic allocation for larger sizes. If you have to handle allocation errors, an member for initializing the class is what you need. Thus, the header will only provide the minimal information necessary for other files (structure and size, not data).

If you want to be able to read your code later, I also suggest that you use meaningful variables names (their sizes is not a problem).

That limit of 100 looks like code smells to me. Why not use dynamic allocation and unrestricted size? you could simply push new token values in a collection when you build them. The default values should only be in the token's constructor, not in a array with a dummy size. What if later you extend your parser to handle more tokens? hard-coded maximum values for arrays are a bad practice if you want your code to evolve. When you reach the limit, you often experience bugs before you notice what's wrong.